# change the ribbon if new outlook-folder is selected

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin

I want to show/hide Buttons depending on the Name of the actual Folder.

No Problem to do this with

```
    Me.btn1.Visible = True 'or false, whatever is necessary
```

But: how can I check for a change of the current Folder?

Thanks
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ribbon XML must specify the getVisible callback name.

Call IRibbonUI.Invalidate, Outlook will then invoke your getVisible/getEnabled callbacks.

IRibbonUI can be cached when Outlook invokes your onLoad callback (specified on the customUI XML element).

Comment: I am sorry, but I am more or less a beginner in visual Studio and do not really understand to much of what you say. Have you got any example/code together with a remark where to put the code? Thanks Max

Comment: You might want to start at http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=36. Are you using the old CommandBars API to add button or the new Ribbon based API?